# Generate HTML table header from comma separated list

Tags: c#, csv, html-table

Is there a way to build HTML table header from comma separated list?

I am using reflection to get properties name from one class. Before that I am defining which properties I want to exclude form that list.

```
 var toExclude = new HashSet<string>
     {
         "ID",
         "SubSystemID",
         "System",
         "Component",
         "ReferenceNumber",
         "IsValid"
     };

var propsIndividuals = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
                       Where(property => !toExclude.Contains(property.Name));

var header = string.Join(", ", propsIndividuals.Select(p => p.Name.ToString()).ToArray());
```

For table content I was using HtmTableRow:

```
foreach (var invalidIndividual in mailMessageObject.InvalidIndividuals)
{
        rowIndividuals = new HtmlTableRow();
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.FirstName});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.Surname});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.MiddleName});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.DateOfBirth});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.Gender});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.Address1});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.Address2});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.Address3});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.Address4});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.City});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.PostalCode});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.Country});
        rowIndividuals.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell {InnerText = invalidIndividual.NationalID});
        tableIndividuals.Rows.Add(rowIndividuals);
}
```

Anybody has idea how to pull properties names from that comma separated array, and put them to a new row, that I can append to table and use it as a header?

Probably there is a better way to pull strings with names with reflection. Maybe I should store them in a list of strings or something like that. 
Any suggestion on how to handle this as much as cleaner it can be would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You may be could use the example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerow.htmltablerow(v=vs.110).aspx).

Update your code snippet like that :

```
var toExclude = new HashSet<string>
{
    "ID",
    "SubSystemID",
    "System",
    "Component",
    "ReferenceNumber",
    "IsValid"
};

var propsIndividuals = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
                       Where(property => !toExclude.Contains(property.Name));

var rowHeader = new new HtmlTableRow("th")

foreach (var property in propsIndividuals)
{
    rowHeader.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = property.Name });
}

tableIndividuals.Rows.Add(rowHeader);
```